# borderStyle appcelerator

Tags: android, titanium, textfield

I have the following code, but the result is quite different from what I thought was going to be (ios verion).

What am I doing wrong?

```
//creating the textfield for our loan amount input
var tfAmount = Titanium.UI.createTextField({
    width: 140,
    height: 30,
    top: 100,
    right: 20,
    borderStyle:Titanium.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED,
    returnKeyType:Titanium.UI.RETURNKEY_DONE,
    hintText: '1000.00',
    keyboardToolbar: [flexSpace,buttonDone],
    keyboardType:Titanium.UI.KEYBOARD_PHONE_PAD
});
view.add(tfAmount);
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What did you think it would look like? The top version? That looks Android -esque to me.

Comment: the second pic is the same script on the iphone simu. what should i change or do make the android version look like the iphone one?

Comment: which titanium sdk you are using ??have you tried this code on some other titanium sdk (Ti 2.1.2 etc)

Comment: madnan, sdk 2.0.1GA2, and I also have 3.0.2GA, which one should I use in order to comply with the new iphone app req?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code. Its working fine for me.

```
   var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor : 'black'
});
var view = Titanium.UI.createView({
    backgroundColor : 'pink',
    top : '2%',
    height : '40%'
});
win.add(view);

/* Loan Label and TextField*/

var loanLabel = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    top : '5%',
    left : '1%',
    width : Titanium.UI.SIZE,
    height : Titanium.UI.SIZE,
    color : 'black',
    text : 'Loan amount : $ ',
    font : {
        fontWeight : 'bold'
    }

})

view.add(loanLabel);
var loanAmount = Titanium.UI.createTextField({
    width : '50%',
    height : Titanium.UI.SIZE,
    top : '5%',
    //color: 'black',
    right : '1%',
    borderStyle : Titanium.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED,
    returnKeyType : Titanium.UI.RETURNKEY_DONE,
    hintText : '1000.00',
    keyboardType : Titanium.UI.KEYBOARD_PHONE_PAD
});
view.add(loanAmount);

/* Interest Rate Label and TextField*/
var irLabel = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    top : '50%',
    left : '1%',
    width : Titanium.UI.SIZE,
    height : Titanium.UI.SIZE,
    color : 'black',
    text : 'Interest Rate : % ',
    font : {
        fontWeight : 'bold'
    }

})

view.add(irLabel);
var tfAmount = Titanium.UI.createTextField({
    width : '50%',
    height : Titanium.UI.SIZE,
    top : '50%',
    //color: 'black',
    right : '1%',
    borderStyle : Titanium.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED,
    returnKeyType : Titanium.UI.RETURNKEY_DONE,
    value : '6',
    borderColor : 'none',
    font : {
        fontWeight : 'bold'
    },
    keyboardType : Titanium.UI.KEYBOARD_PHONE_PAD
});
view.add(tfAmount);

win.open();
```

Comment: madnan, thanks. It appeares that I have a lot more control this way on the positioning. It does not look as good as iphone but I can probably live with that.

Comment: For different screen resolutions you have to give % or platform height or width values because there are multiple screens in android and your hardcoded values may not fit and that's why  distortion occurs